# how can i solve error : E (7870) esp_https_ota: Complete headers were not received

Tags: https, esp32, espressif-idf

I'm working on OTA project via https, I'm using advanced https example provided by Espressif and I'm having these errors:

```
I (7690) advanced_https_ota_example: Reading Image Description
E (7870) esp_https_ota: Complete headers were not received
E (7870) advanced_https_ota_example: esp_https_ota_read_img_desc failed
I (7870) advanced_https_ota_example: OTA abort
E (7880) advanced_https_ota_example: ESP_HTTPS_OTA upgrade failed
```

I've tried the same code with http and it works good,do you have any idea on how I can solve these errors?

Comment: Hi zineb, welcome to SO. Unfortunately your post doesn't have enough details. Instead of saying "advanced https example provided by Espressif" please post your code. Also you haven't explained how you are serving the OTA images - what server, how it's configured etc. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)